# How to determine how much space 1 row will take in Postgres db?

Tags: postgresql

I'm very new to Postgres so my math could be off here...

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE audit (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    content_id VARCHAR (50) NULL, 
    type VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL, 
    size bigint NOT NULL, 
    timestamp1 timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(), 
    timestamp2 timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW());
```

I want to make some estimations on how much space 1 row would occupy. So I did something like this:

```
1 row = id + content_id + type + size + timestamp1 + timestamp2 
     = 8 + 100 + 50 + 8 + 8 + 8 bytes
     = 182 bytes
```

I also created this same table in my local postgres but the numbers are not matching

```
INSERT INTO public.audit(
    content_id, type, size)
    VALUES ('aaa', 'bbb', 100);


SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('audit') );  -- returns 24 kb

INSERT INTO public.audit(
    content_id, type, size)
    VALUES ('aaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 100000000000);

SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('audit') ); -- still returns 24 kb
```

Which brings me to think that Postgres reserves a space of 24 kb to start with and as I put in more data it will get incremented by 132 bytes once I go beyond 24 kb? But something inside me says that can't be right.

I want to see how much space 1 row would occupy in Postgres db so I can analyze how much data I can potentially store in it.

### Edit

After reading more I've come up with this, is it correct?

```
1 row =
23 (heaptupleheader)
+ 1 (padding)
+ 8 (id)
+ 50 (content_id)
+ 6 (padding)
+ 100 (type)
+ 4 (padding)
+ 8 (size)
+ 8 (timestamp)
+ 8 (timestamp)
= 216 bytes
```

Comment: This might be better asked at the sister site: https://DBA.StackExchange.com

Comment: If you want to see the real size of each row, you can use `select id, pg_column_size(a) from audit a`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That "something inside me says that can't be right" is wrong. Actually trying id determine the size of each row is impractical. You can calculate the average row, and given a large number of rows the better that average get. Part of that reason is variable length columns. Your definition varchar(50) does not required bytes of storage unless unless it contains 50 bytes, if it has 20 then it only takes up 20 bytes (plus overhead), even then it's not exact as the padding may change. The definition only specifies the Maximum not the actual, storage is on actual.  
As far a your 24kb that doesn't seem out-of-line at all. Keep in mind that physical I/O is the slowest possible individual operation and trying to adjust to individual rows for I/O would bring your system to a screeching halt. Postgres therefore only reads in full blocks (and allocates space the same), and/or multiple blocks. Typically with a [block size](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-preset.html) of 8K (8192 bytes). This is the trade off I/O performance vs. space allocation. It appears your system has a multi-block read of 3 blocks (??). If anything is surprising it would that is is that small.  
In short trying to get the size of a row not piratical, instead get several hundred representative rows and calculate the average.   
BTW you can change the length just by rearranging your columns:

```
1 row =
23 (heaptupleheader)
+ 1 (padding)
+ 8 (id)
+ 8 (size)
+ 8 (timestamp)
+ 8 (timestamp)
+ 50 (content_id)
+ 2 (padding)      (if content contains all 50 char)
+ 100 (type)       (if type contains all 100 char)
= 208 bytes
```

Comment: thanks a lot! this gives me a lot to think. interesting to see how rearranging columns can save space.

Comment: Actually a `varchar(50)` column can take up to 200 bytes depending on the encoding being use.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name interesting. could you point me to some doc/wiki where i can read more about it?

Comment: @90abyss: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding